# MySQL SELECT with JOIN - how to code correct

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, `client` and `application`. Basically they are setup like this:

Let's say table `client` has 2 records (rows) only:

```
ID | company         | street     | city   | country
1    Tea-Export Ltd.   Wallstreet   Mumbai   India
2    Tea-Import Ltd.   Mainstream   London   United Kingdom
```

The table `application` has one row only:

```
ID | app_num | seller | buyer
1    3002      1        2
```

A query to the application table parses the `app_num` (3002) as a search parameter.
And the query should result in one array only with this structure:

```
$app_data {
  [ID] => [1]
  [app_num] => [3002]
  seller {
    [company] => [Tea-Export Ltd]
    [street] => [Wallstreet]
    [city] => [Mumbai]
    [country] => [India]
  } 
  buyer {
    [company] => [Tea-Import Ltd]
    [street] => [Mainstreet]
    [city] => [London]
    [country] => [United Kingdom]
  } 
}
```

I know this can be achieved through a SELECT statement with a JOIN.
And there are a lot of JOIN examples in the internet, but none of the ones I have studied fits straight to my example. So any help is appreciated to build the correct MySQL statement.

EDIT :

The solution from Jehad Ahmad Jaghoub basicly works but must be extented and completed to fetch all adress columns from `seller` and `buyer` like this :

```
 (' SELECT 
    s.ID,
    s.app_num,
    a.company AS seller_company ,
    a.street AS seller_street ,
    a.house_num AS seller_house_num ,
    a.postal_code AS seller_postal_code ,
    a.city AS seller_city ,
    a.country AS seller_country ,
    b.company AS buyer_company ,
    b.street AS buyer_street, 
    b.postal_code AS buyer_postal_code ,
    b.city AS buyer_city ,
    b.country AS buyer_country 

  FROM `application`  AS s
  LEFT JOIN clients AS a ON s.seller = a.id  
  LEFT JOIN clients AS b ON s.buyer = b.id  
  WHERE s.app_num = :app_num'); 

$app_data {
  [ID] => [1]
  [app_num] => [3002]
  [seller_company] => [Tea-Export Ltd]
  [seller_street] => [Wallstreet]
  [seller_house_num] => [45a]
  [seller_postal_code] => [400036]
  [seller_city] => [Mumbai]
  [seller_country] => [India]
  [buyer_company] => [Tea-Import Ltd]
  [buyer_street] => [Mainstreet]
  [buyer_house_num] => [345]
  [buyer_postal_code] => []
  [buyer_city] => [London]
  [buyer_country] => [United Kingdom]
}
```

But it's hell of a lot of code because one has to select each column separately. Also it becomes more complicated in my case because the country column is actually another ID (country_id) pointing to a separate country table which incorporates two more JOIN for seller and buyer. AND there are not only seller and buyer but also agent and consignee columns which I left away for simplicity.
Also it produces a one dimensional array only. So, is there a more easy solutions available, also to get a multidimensional array like my example above ?

Comment: You will need to JOIN with the same table twice, with different aliases.

Comment: Can you update your question with the current query that you have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try this? I think this is what you want. If not, please let me know.

```
SELECT 
  s.*,
  a.company AS SellerCompany,
  b.company AS BuyerCompany
FROM `application`  AS s
LEFT JOIN client AS a ON s.seller = a.id AND s.id = 1 
LEFT JOIN client AS b ON s.buyer = b.id AND s.id = 1 ;
```

Comment: see my EDIT above

Comment: `s.*,
  a.*,
  b.*`

Comment: `SELECT 
  s.*,
  a.*,
  b.*
FROM `application`  AS s
LEFT JOIN client AS a ON s.seller = a.id AND s.id = 1 
LEFT JOIN client AS b ON s.buyer = b.id AND s.id = 1 ;`
try to see the result of array on server side for this SQL as i try it on phpmyadmin its work but have same field name it can be on server side Called as B.id or B.name ?

Comment: `SELECT s.*, a.*, b.* FROM application AS s LEFT JOIN client AS a ON s.seller = a.id  LEFT JOIN client AS b ON s.buyer = b.id`
sorry i can edit comment try this will give you multidimensional array ?

Comment: currently I use your solution as I posted above and it works perfect. So I will accept your answer. To above multidemensional array solution I will make a separate edit. But it may take some days. BTW you can make a separate answer from this, so I might accept this later. Thanks for your time anyway, heldped my saving time.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to JOIN with the same table twice using different aliases:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.app_num, seller.*, buyer.*  
FROM Application a 
INNER JOIN Client seller on a.seller = seller.ID
INNER JOIN Client buyer ON a.buyer = buyer.ID
WHERE a.app_num='3002'
```

See if this works. `seller.*` will give all the seller details and `buyer.*` will give all the buyer details. You can also change the select fields if you only need certain columns.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work. When I am right than because `seller` and `buyer` are not `tables` but `colums` on the `client` table

Comment: my comment above is not true - forget it

Comment: ok this works, but only either with `seller` or `buyer` depending which one is first in the SELECT statement. So how to complete youre answer so that both are selected ? Also it generates no multidimensional array, but thats no handicap.

Comment: It does not generate an array because it's a SQL query. You still need to run the query using PHP or something and then that will return the array. This answer is to illustrate how JOINs could be used in a case like yours. If you tweak it further then you might be able to use it for different cases.

Comment: Well the query is embedded in a PDO statement. It's not shown above for simplicity. So how to get a multidimensional array anyway ?

Comment: I am not entirely sure but if for whatever reason you absolutely need a multi-dimensional array, then you can possible look into a nested subquery and/or JSON. A single MySQL query would probable not give you the multi-dimensional array that you are looking for.